# Create a description box with changing text for video playlist with HTML CSS Javacript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="main-video-container">
      <video src="video1.mp4" loop controls controlsList="nodownload" class="main-video"></video>
      <h3 class="main-vid-title">VIDEO 1</h3>
   </div>

   <div class="video-list-container">

      <div class="list active">
         <video src="video1.mp4" poster="" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 1</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video2.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 2</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video3.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 3</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video4.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 4</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video5.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 5</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video6.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 6</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="list">
         <video src="video7.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
         <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 7</h3>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
html {
   margin:0; padding:0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   outline: none; border:none;
   text-decoration: none;
}

body{
   background-color: coral;
   padding: 20px;
   font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
   background: url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   text-align: center;
}

.container{
   max-width: 1200px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: flex-start;
   gap: 20px;
}

.container .main-video-container{
   flex: 1 1 700px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0 20px 40px #528bc6;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding:15px;
}

.container .main-video-container .main-video{
   margin-bottom: 7px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100%;
}

.container .main-video-container .main-vid-title{
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #444;
}

.container .video-list-container{
   flex:1 1 350px;
   height: 485px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
   background-color: #fff;
   padding:15px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
   width: 10px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
   background-color: #444;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   gap:15px;
   padding:10px;
   background-color: #eee;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list:last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container .video-list-container .list.active{
   background-color: #444;
}

.container .video-list-container .list.active .list-title{
   color:#fff;
}

.container .video-list-container .list .list-video{
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list .list-title{
   font-size: 17px;
   color:#444;
   text-align: left;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
   visibility: hidden;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
   visibility: visible;
   
}
```

And my Javascript

```
let videoList = document.querySelectorAll('.video-list-container .list');

videoList.forEach(vid =>{
   vid.onclick = () =>{
      videoList.forEach(remove =>{remove.classList.remove('active')});
      vid.classList.add('active');
      let src = vid.querySelector('.list-video').src;
      let title = vid.querySelector('.list-title').innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('.main-video-container .main-video').src = src;
      document.querySelector('.main-video-container .main-vid-title').innerHTML = title;
   };
});
```

How could I get a separate container below the video to have a description of the video, as well as the option for links, the content of the container should change based on what video was selected. Thank you guys so much! It's my first time posting here!

Also I'm very aware this isn't upwork so I don't expect you to style it for me if its too much work :)

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k10wrftu/

I looked into using JavaScript to replace text but I couldn't get it to change more than once, when you clicked another video.

Comment: You don't seem to have made any attempt to solve this problem yourself.  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Make an attempt to solve this.  If you run into an issue modify your question so that it includes an [mre] demonstrating the issue you ran into.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm sorry that's my bad, I just wasn't sure where to begin, but that's okay, I guess ill just have to look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are already doing something like that with the video `src` and `title`.

Just add another element below title `main-vid-title` in the main container, e.g. `<div class="main-vid-infobox">` and change its content.

Using a custom `[data-*]` attribute (called here`data-info`) in element `.list` containing some relevant information about the video you can put information in the main container `.main-vid-infobox`. Up to you to extract that info from the video Metadata or some online Movie Database.

Obviously, you can use any element, anywhere in the viewport to show the extended information...

**[data-*] attribute** [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

**Snippet**: sample use of the `[data-*]` attribute is in the HTML. No changes made in CSS and the JS is commented.

```js
// Get the list of videos
let videoList = document.querySelectorAll(".video-list-container .list");

// Save references to main containers, only once
let mainVideo = document.querySelector(".main-video-container .main-video");
let mainTitle = document.querySelector(".main-video-container .main-vid-title");
let mainInfo  = document.querySelector(".main-video-container .main-vid-infobox");

// Assign eventListeners
videoList.forEach((vid) => {
    vid.onclick = () => {
        videoList.forEach((remove) => { remove.classList.remove("active"); });

        selectVideo(vid); // Nicely hidden inside a 'black box'
    };
});

// Moved to a function to have a 'First Run' capability
const selectVideo = (vid) => {
    vid.classList.add("active");

    mainVideo.src       = vid.querySelector(".list-video").src;
    mainTitle.innerHTML = vid.querySelector(".list-title").innerHTML;

    // If info available use that, otherwise empty string
    mainInfo.innerHTML = (vid.dataset.info) ? vid.dataset.info : "" ;
};

// First Run, select the first video in the list, if any... 
if (videoList.length > 0) selectVideo(videoList[0]);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700|Lato:300,400,700&display=swap");

* {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 20px;
}

.container .main-video-container {
    flex: 1 1 700px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px #528bc6;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

.container .main-video-container .main-video {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .main-video-container .main-vid-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #444;
}

.container .video-list-container {
    flex: 1 1 350px;
    height: 485px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container .video-list-container .list.active {
    background-color: #444;
}

.container .video-list-container .list.active .list-title {
    color: #fff;
}

.container .video-list-container .list .list-video {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .video-list-container .list .list-title {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #444;
    text-align: left;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
    visibility: hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-video-container">
        <video src="" loop controls controlsList="nodownload" class="main-video"></video>
        <h3 class="main-vid-title"></h3>
        <div class="main-vid-infobox">no video selected</div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-list-container">

        <div class="list" data-info="Video 1 extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" poster="" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 1</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-info="Video 2, again extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 2</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-info="Video 3 etc. extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 3</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-info="Video 4, you got the picture! Extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 4</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-noinfo="oops...">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 5 (has no info, oops)</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-info="Video 6, This is getting boring! Extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 6</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="list" data-info="And... 7, finally done! Extended information">
            <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" class="list-video"></video>
            <h3 class="list-title">VIDEO 7</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this might be pushing it, but am I right in assuming you couldn't add links to the said custom attribute text? How could you go about doing that?

Comment: @jparko simply search online for *mdn data attribute* and you will get a list with specs and examples. And while you're here, accept the anser so it gets the green checkmark... Thanks!